# How do you RUN npm module node-inspector in OpenShift environment?

Tags: node.js, openshift, node-inspector

I have made these failing attempts are on the OpenShift gear via SSH.

Attempt-1:

```
node-debug app.js
Node Inspector v0.12.7
Cannot start the server at 127.0.0.1:8080. Error: listen EACCES.
```

Attempt-2:

```
node-inspector
Node Inspector v0.12.7
Cannot start the server at 0.0.0.0:8080. Error: listen EACCES.
```

Attempt-3:

```
node --debug app.js
debugger listening on port 5858
Failed to open socket on port 5858, waiting 1000 ms before retrying
```

I don't know what the correct method is to get an installed node-inspector running in an OpenShift Node.JS Gear.

Comment: Did you find any more information on this problem?

Comment: I was able to get it installed on the OpenShift environment but never able to get it running. I can not believe I am the only one in the OpenShift World wanting to do this.  Node-inspector is a great debugging tool. At some point you have to take your node app from your local network and put it in the cloud. Does that mean debugging is done? NO! So how can you continue to debug effectively? Node-Inspector is the obvious answer but no one has come back to me, not even Red Hat, with a solution. Do you have a cookbook recipe that works?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a solution. I'm thinking maybe port forwarding may help to solve this.

Comment: Yes, I did too. It doesn't. Port forwarding is necessary but is not the missing part. :(  Thx. Wish I could afford to go to one of these Red Hat Conferences that cost $1400 to $2200, to push for an answer. But that is above the lone dev pay grade.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is way too late or if you have found a solution.

I've managed to get this working in OpenShift 'origin' on my local machine
I made use of the node4-rhel7 image so the following is specific (i.e entrypoint and adding to /usr/bin in the image), so change it accordingly

Here are the steps :-

- create or update a Dockerfile that gave me the correct permissions (rw) for my node app
- install node-inspector (npm install node-inspector --save)
- add this script (call it start.sh - in a folder root/usr/bin) also remember to set execute permissions

  `if [ $# gt 0 ] && [ "$1" == "debug"]
  then
    # assume default debug port of 5858
    node --debug name-of-startup.js
    node_modules/node-inspector/bin/inspector.js -p 9000 --save-live-edit=true
  else
    node name-of-startup.js
  fi`
- add a script called container-entrypoint also in a folder root/usr/bin

  `#!/bin/bash
  exec "$@"`
- add this to your Dockerfile

  - ADD root /
  - ENTRYPOINT ["container-entrypoint"]
  - CMD ["start.sh"]
- docker build -t name-of-your-image:version .
- oc edit dc/name-of-your-node-pod
- add port: 9000 and protocol: TCP in "spec.containers.ports"
- add "command": [ "start.sh","debug"] in "spec.containers"
- update the image to the newly built one on your local docker (name-of-your-image:version)
- save (this will re-deploy your app) and execute 'oc get ep' (to get the endpoint of you app)
- open chrome with with url http://your-app-endpoint:9000/?port=5858
- you can now debug/set breakpoints etc and change code via the chrome interface - primitive but works like a charm :)